# Why do I need to `yield env.timeout(0)` to hand over control in simpy?

Tags: python, simpy

I'm playing around with simpy for robotics simulations, and i started off with writing a trivial ping-pong game with two rackets called ping and pong. It works as it should only when I add a `yield env.timeout(0)` to let one player provide an opportunity for the opposite player to catch his turn. If I skip this noop(?), the first player grabs the ball all the time. Here is my code:

```
import simpy

ball_wait = 1

def racket(env, name, ball):
    while True:
        # Let the first user catch the ball
        with ball.request() as req:  # Create a waiting resource
            yield req   # Wait and get the ball
 
            # The time it takes for the ball to arrive. This can
            # be used to plan the strategy of how to hit the ball.
            yield env.timeout(ball_wait)
            print(env.now, name)

        # "Sleep" to get the other user have his turn.
        yield env.timeout(0)

env = simpy.Environment()
ball = simpy.Resource(env, capacity = 1)

env.process(racket(env, 'Ping', ball))
env.process(racket(env, 'Pong', ball))

env.run(until=10)
print('Done!')
```

My question is why do I need the `env.timeout(0)`? I also wonder if there is some some other (nicer?) strategy of handing over control between two processes? I also played around with `process.interrupt()` but it seems to me like an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of this problem can be found in the [simpy-users mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/p/simpy/mailman/message/32058134/)

What Dov discovered was actually a [bug in SimPy](https://bitbucket.org/simpy/simpy/issue/47/resourcerequest-directly-after) that has been fixed in Version 3.0.4.